# Add stream order attributes to a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-pro

My objective is to assign stream order number for each polyline. There is a field within streams but every row lists "0" in this field.

I have a shapefile with all of the streams as polylines. I have contours for the county.

I do not have a raster/DEM file.

How can I assign stream order for each stream polyline without editing the attribute table manually?

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions [Stream order method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/452213/stream-order-method)

Comment: The prior question said to change it or repost.  I changed it but it wasn't re-opened.   It wasn't clear to me why it was closed.

Comment: The close message said "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations". The Question asked "Does it make sense for me to...{list of things}" Whether it would make sense was quite subjective. You've changed it, but Reopening isn't instantaneous.

Comment: Ok,  I appreciate the feedback.  Is there a timeline for that question to be reopened or should I delete it and let this one remain?